# Error: list indices must be integers or slices, not list - while deploying pipeline model in flask

Tags: python, list, machine-learning, flask, pipeline

Im trying to deploy my model generated using Pipeline. It works fine on jupyter or spyder notebooks. However while deploying im getting the below error:
***list indices must be integers or slices, not list***

Here is my code for app.py (deployment in flask) after importing the libraries:

```
class FeatureSelector( BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin ):
#Class Constructor 
def __init__( self, feature_names ):
    self._feature_names = feature_names 

#Return self nothing else to do here    
def fit( self, X, y =None):
    return self 

#Method that describes what we need this transformer to do
def transform( self, X, y = None):
    return X[ self._feature_names ] 
pass


class NumericalTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
#Class Constructor
def __init__( self, MPA_log = True):
    self._MPA_log = MPA_log

#Return self, nothing else to do here
def fit( self, X, y = None):
    return self 

#Custom transform method we wrote that creates aformentioned features and drops redundant ones 
def transform(self, X, y = None):
    if self._MPA_log:
        X['Monthly Premium Auto'] = np.log(X['Monthly Premium Auto'])
    return X.values
pass
```

Passing the functions created for pipeline

```
app = Flask(__name__)
model = pickle.load(open('model.pkl', 'rb'))

@app.route('/')
def home():
     return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/predict',methods=['POST'])
def predict():
'''
For rendering results on HTML GUI
'''
    int_features = [int(x) for x in request.form.values()]
    final_features = [np.array(int_features)]
    prediction = model.predict(final_features)

    output = round(np.exp(prediction[0]),2)


    return render_template('index.html', prediction_text='Customer Lifetime Value $ {}'.format(output))

if __name__ == "__main__":  

    model = pickle.load(open('model.pkl','rb'))

    print("loaded OK")

    app.run(debug=True)
```

I am trying to find a solution to this since a very long time. Any help would be great.
Thank you.

Comment: what line is the error?

Comment: It comes when reading the model 'model.predict(final_features)'. The model is a pipeline, not sure what is causing this. The same code ran properly when the model was not a pipeline.

Comment: Please let me know if you need any more information on this, i can help you understand this better

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this error by converting my output into a pandas DataFrame. This has helped with all the errors that my model was facing with formats and data types.
Simple changed the input data to a dataframe.